# Internal Forward in Silex Without a Sending a 301/302 to the Browser

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm using Silex's internal forwarding to map public URLs to internal URLs i.e. `my.domain.com/something` actually serves `my.domain.com/something_else` using

```
$subRequest = Request::create(
    $redirect,
    $method, 
    [], // params
    $request->cookies->all(), 
    $request->files->all(), 
    $request->server->all()
);

if ($request->getSession())
{
    $subRequest->setSession($request->getSession());
}

return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, true);
```

However, in Chrome's inspection tool, this appears as a 301 to the resulting page, which then serves the result. Is this "by design" as it represents an interesting security problem? Are there ways around this limitation?

While I can't post code for the `something_else` route controller, the gist is

```
// controller provider
$controller_factory->match('/something_else/{param}', function(...) {
    include 'path/to/some/file';
});
```

and

```
// some/file - prepares a file to be downloaded
...
return new BinaryFileResponse();
```

there are no RedirectResponses in that file

**Edit** I over simplified in the above example. In reality, `/something` is a random string (i.e. `/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` which maps to one of many internal routes (`-> /something_else, -> /something_else_2, -> etc`).

Comment: can you show us the controller for the ```/something_else``` route?

Comment: @mTorres while I can't actually share the code in the controller, I've edited my original post to include a gist. If it's not enough, please let me know.

Comment: Just call the method the other route calls.

Comment: I would like to not have to re-implement the entire controller schema inside this method. I over simplified the question, `/something` is actually a random string which is parsed into an actual route, which could be one of many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be a single character fix: `/`.

Given the following definition:

```
$controller_factory->match('/something_else/{param}/', function($app, $param) { ... });
$controller_factory->match('/something', function($app) {
    // do the redirect to /something_else/{param}
    $redirect = '/something_else/hello';
    ...
});
```

Can you spot it? It turns out that Symfony was intelligently forwarding routes without trailing slashes that matched routes with trailing slashes to the route with the slash. My issue was that I was "correctly" resolving `/something_else/something` from my string of random characters (see my edit if you missed this), but it was INCORRECT in the sense that it should be resolving to `/something_else/something/` (notice the trailing slash)

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. I believe it is your `something_else` controller doesn't like the sub-request and returns redirect response, which your `something` controller unconditionally returns to the browser.

It can be anything. Silex is a micro-framework, which means things can be implemented in hundreds of different ways, and it is hardly possible to advise anything without seeing the actual code. It is the flip side of flexibility it  brings. It may be `RedirectableUrlMatcher`, or anything in your controller, router, included files, error handler or middleware, which results with redirect response.

Consider this even more oversimplified single-script app example:

```
<?php
// web/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get(
    '/the-only-functional',
    function() use ($app) {
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(
            $app['request']->get('q')
        );
    }
);

$app->get(
    '/{whatever}',
    function($whatever) use ($app) {
        $subRequest = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create(
            '/the-only-functional',
            'GET',
            ['q'=>$whatever]
        );
        $response = $app->handle($subRequest);

        if (200 != $response->getStatusCode()) {
            throw new \Exception(
                "Aha, that's where the problem lies"
                . $response->getStatusCode() . ":"
                . $response->getContent()
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }
)->value('whatever', 'nothing');

$app->run();
```

with http server running as:

```
php -S localhost:8081 -d "date.timezone=UTC" -t web  web/index.php
```

you can try different permutations:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8081/
curl -v http://localhost:8081/blah-blah
curl -v http://localhost:8081/the-only-functional?q=direct
curl -v http://localhost:8081/?q=this+example+does+not+forward+query+string
```

and you **always** get 200 response.

Unfortunately, without sharing the code, you are on your own debugging your app. The only sensible advice is to analyse the sub-response before returning it, and may be log a backtrace to localise the problem.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I really appreciate it. I'll take a look and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at Sub Request :
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html

```
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$app->get('/something', function (Application $app, Request $request) {
    $subRequest = Request::create('/something_else', ...);
    $response = $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);

    return $response;
});
```

Comment: That's what I did, if you look at the first code example.